# Не устанавливается gulp в Ubuntu как исправить?

Tags: linux, node.js, ubuntu, gulp, npm

При установки gulp глобально получаю ошибку, добавление sudo не помогает(см.скрин)
[image: Ошибки]

Кажется мои манипуляции с настройками порушали всё, пробовал все удалять и устанавливать снова, не получилось, но как я понял если запустить команду с npx gulp [task] то работает я не понял почему. До этого всё работала исправно и без прибавки npx, хотелось бы вернуться к этому снова. Как?

Comment: `sudo npm cache clean --force && npm cache clean --force && sudo npm i -g gulp-cli` если попробовать так?

Comment: @nörbörnën Магия какая-то), вроде работает! Спасибо! А что было написано в командах поясни, пожалуйста, что произошло?

Comment: я попросил npm очистить локальный кеш пакетов под твоим пользователем и под root. и команда глобальной установки gulp-cli